# How to add the image / icon to the "Uninstall a Program" list in the Control Panel

Tags: visual-studio-2012, installshield

I would like to add the image / icon that I currently have for the executable to my program instllation in the list in "Uninstall a Program" window. Now I can see a small Default Image that comes up. However I would like to have a image like how other installations have like the "Blue S" for Skype, etc.

Do I have an option to add it via Visual Studio ? I use InstallSheild Limited Edition for Packaging.

Frankly, I do not know the correct keyword to search for it in Google. I tried but in vain. Apologies if its a straight forward explanation.

I have attached the image to explain better.

[image: Sample Image]

Comment: Don't know if you can do it with IS Limited, but here are some more details: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/ui_and_localization/configure_arp_appearance.html    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367593(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the links but they are not what I essentially need. I was able to find the answer. Will post the solution in a while. Thanks again..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is pretty straight forward but I was not able to find any relating documentation on this. You can set the icon for the add/remove programs window from via the InstallSheild wizard itself.

This is illustrated as in "InstallSheild Limited Edition"

•   In the InstallSheild Project Assistant Screen, Choose Application Information (The first step in the wizard)

•   From the left pane, "other places" choose the "General Information" Link

•   Click Yes, in the popup that shows up

•   Scroll Down to the "Add/Remove Programs" Part of the List

•   Choose the icon of your choice in the "Display Icon" field and save the settings

[image: Image from InstallSheild]

Comment: I looked at this screen a half dozen times and missed that every time.... Thanks.